# WordPress website loads but is not displayed until page scrolled

Tags: theme-development, themes, performance, google-chrome

I have built a WordPress website. It loads without problems until recently, but now I am facing a strange behaviour.

The website loads, but nothing is displayed until I scroll the page down, or change the browser's window size. Then the page immediately appears.

I am having this problem with Chrome browsers only (both normal and incognito modes).

Website:
[netsooq.com/cloudtender/](http://netsooq.com/cloudtender/)

Comment: It seems to load fine for me, is the issue resolved? If not can you detail browser (chrome, firefox etc?) and OS (windows, mac, linux) you are having the issue in?

Comment: Don't know why it does not work at your end. It works alright even with No-Script/Script-Safe enabled. What does the Chrome Developer Tools tell you? Can you list the plugins that you have enabled? Any JavaScript frameworks that you/your script may have included?

Comment: Works on chrome for me.

Answer (score 4):

I have visited your site in several browsers, including Chrome, and everything is working fine. The sole fact that you only experience the problem only in chrome, already means that this question is about the browser, not about WordPress. So, it's off topic here.

Anyway, Chrome is known to show this kind of behaviour under certain circumstances. Add-blockers may be the culprit. Rtl-languages seem to be vulnerable. There is no real fix that I know of, but one of the solutions that might do it, is to include a little piece of javascript that scrolls the site down 1 pixel, thus triggering the rendering mechanism that was failing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).load(function() {
        $( "body" ).animate({
            scrollTop: 1
        });
    });
});
```

If that doesn't work, StackOverflow is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: Can confirm site is slow on my end, but loads fine, no JS errors in console, too. Using AdGuard as a blocker, plus Disconnect in Chrome, shows up fine anyway, even though both together are quite strict to scripts very often.

Comment: Now the issue appears. I have not performed your solution yet. But now the issue is there. I have confirmed it with Chrome on Mac OS X

Comment: I do not think the issue is related to plugins. It also appears on Chrome for Mobile (Android and iOS)